# Error when starting Apache Ignite inside OSGI container

Tags: osgi, ignite

I'm currently trying to start Apache Ignite inside OSGI container, but I'm getting this error:

> Failed to start Ignite via OSGi Activator [errMsg=Failed to find empty
>   constructor for class:
>   o.a.i.i.processors.platform.websession.PlatformDotNetSessionLockResult]class
>   org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to find empty
>   constructor for class:
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.websession.PlatformDotNetSessionLockResult
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.constructor(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:976)
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:265)
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.registerPredefinedType(BinaryContext.java:1053)
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.registerPredefinedType(BinaryContext.java:1038)
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.(BinaryContext.java:349)
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.start(CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.java:207)
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1739)
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:977)
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2014)
>   at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1723)
>   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1151)
>   at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:671) at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:596) at
>   org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:327) at
>   org.apache.ignite.osgi.IgniteAbstractOsgiContextActivator.start(IgniteAbstractOsgiContextActivator.java:108)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1002)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:354)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581) at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449) at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
>   at aQute.launcher.Launcher.startBundles(Launcher.java:517) at
>   aQute.launcher.Launcher.activate(Launcher.java:423) at
>   aQute.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:301) at
>   aQute.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:147)

I've used the minimal setup described in Apache Ignite documentation website:

ignite-core

ignite-osgi

javax cache api

I've extenteded IgniteAbstractOsgiContextActivator and I added a minimal configuration.

Comment: What's your Ignite version and JDK?

Comment: I've tried with 2.6.0 and 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT
JVM version 1.8.0_111

Comment: The issue is likely because Ignite can't access the class `sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory`. In Java 8 it should be present and easily accessible though. Perhaps there is some OSGi magic preventing it from being accessed.

Comment: Let me try to add this package to the system package of OSGI runtime and test again

Comment: I've checked and ignite-core actually misses that dependency - I see only `sun.misc` in the manifest's `Import-Packages`. So, please confirm that adding that package fixes the problem and I'll file an issue in Ignite's JIRA.

Comment: I've added this package but with no luck to make it work.